# Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

After producing to the kafka, Uncaught exception happen in the log. But successfully produce the feeds to the kafka. I would like to understand why this log appears, its severity and how can I fix it. Thanks!

Kafka dependencies in pom.xml looks like this :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My producer configs looks like this:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> jsonProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 500);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 50000000);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 5048576);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> jsonKkafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(jsonProducerFactory());
}
```

I have this log :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer.close(Ljava/time/Duration;)V
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.closeProducer(KafkaTemplate.java:382) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.lambda$buildCallback$4(KafkaTemplate.java:433) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1235) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:201) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:599) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:575) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:485) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:700) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:532) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:524) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kafka Clients library you are using is incompatible with Spring Kafka and Kafka Stream libraries. This is dependency issues; You could try removing the version from the Kafka Clients dependency to let the default compatible version to be loaded or can explicitly specify a supported version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version><Supported Version></version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The first solution is best - it looks like you are using Spring Boot and he will manage the dependency versions for you. You should always use the dependencies prescribed by the project. You **don't need to use the client version that matches the broker.** Modern clients (since 0.10.2 IIRC) can talk to any broker.

Comment: I removed that Kafka-client dependency, then it works fine. Thank you for the support.